# Trouble Enabling HttpHeaderSecurityFilter in Tomcat 7.0.82

Tags: tomcat, http-headers, tomcat7, clickjacking, strict-transport-security

I have edited the web.xml to enable the HttpHeaderSecurityFilter, added a few params and restarted Tomcat.  I'm not seeing the strict-transport-security in the response header.

I have performed the same steps on several Tomcat 9 installations with the same values in web.xml and it works as expected.

The pertinent entries in web.xml (some of the params are default and I know are not needed but I added while trying to work through this issue):

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>hstsEnabled</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param> 
    <init-param>
        <param-name>hstsMaxAgeSeconds</param-name>
        <param-value>31536000</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>hstsIncludeSubDomains</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>hstsPreload</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>antiClickJackingEnabled</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
        <param-value>DENY</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

ServerInfo:

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.82
Server built:   Sep 29 2017 12:23:15 UTC
Server number:  7.0.82.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_131-b11
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```